# How to prevent jquery to keyup when inside textareas?

Tags: jquery

I have this event binded to my 'body':

```
$('body').bind('keyup', doSomething);
```

But I want to avoid this event inside textareas. Using unbind event when focus on textareas and rebind when blur them costs too much. Is there another way o do that?

Oh, I also tried:

```
$('body:not(textarea)').bind('keyup', doSomething);
```

but didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two ways that come to mind are:

1. Within your existing handler test the `event.target` and do nothing if it is a `textarea`
2. Add a second handler on `textarea` elements that stops propagation of keyup events.

Actual code:

```
 // option 1
 $('body').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="textarea")
       return;

    // your existing non-textarea code here
 });

 // option 2
 $('body').bind('keyup', doSomething);

 $('textarea').bind('keyup', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Demo for option 1: http://jsfiddle.net/XZTaC/

Answer (score 2):

You could add a separate handler to the textarea that stops propagation of the event:

```
$('textarea').bind('keyup', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never though to bind to the body for keyup. I would have approached it differently, like so:

```
$('*').not('textarea').bind('keyup', doSomething);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't stop the event from bubbling up from the textarea...